# How to add a UIView on top of UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, swift4

I'm stuck in a situation where I need to display a UIView on top of a UITableViewController. Have no clue how to proceed with this.

I have a tableView which displays contacts, While the data is being fetched from the server I want to add a UIView(probably an image or activity indicator) on top of my tableView until the data is received.

Comment: Show what you are trying to achieve, describe it better, and provide code that you already tried..

Comment: add some UI ....

Comment: just put a `view` above the `tableView` or put a view as the `tableView`s `tableHeaderView`

Comment: We called it [tableheaderView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Parent ViewController that contains your TableViewController as well as other UIViewController with your overlay view. You can easily manage both and display according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TableView header. You can add it by:

- Draging a view until to the top of the table view in the Interface Builder ([An example here](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/EkSCjfx35nLxtda8eqoEghim0Z2yZFJMColVqqmtgRbnfactaNux3oXZ81DBvV95zH3o88_mz8yjpgE=w472-h312-nc))
- or by code at the UITableView delegate using:

  -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

This should work for both UIViewControllers and UITableViewControllers